# Is it safe to use Pyside in Python interactive mode?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

When I use PySide, I always use Python interactive mode. Is this safe? I want to know how PySide act in Python interactive mode. What is the difference between `Python interactive mode` and `Running from shell calling "python sample.py"` when using PySide.

**P.S.** Don't hesitate to modify this question from grammar point, because I'm English learner. Also from technical point.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by safe?  If you mean safety of the data it is managing it's no more safer or dangerous than the code being run and how the user is interacting with the program than running it normally, with the exception that the interactive shell gives direct access to the entire program state with the full power of the Python language.  However, due to how Qt is structured this can't readily be exploited*, but you still can use it to spawn a window.

Anyway, here is an example:

```
>>> from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
>>> class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
...     def __init__(self):
...         super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
...         self.setObjectName("MainWindow")
...         self.resize(800, 600)
...
>>> app = QtGui.QApplication([])
>>> mw = MainWindow()
>>> exit = QtGui.QAction('&Exit', mw)
>>> exit.triggered.connect(mw.close)
True
>>> menubar = mw.menuBar()
>>> filemenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
>>> filemenu.addAction(exit)
>>> mw.show()
>>> app.exec_()
```

The interactive shell will have stopped responding and control is transferred to the window.  Clicking on file then quit will close the window, resulting in this:

```
0
>>>
```

Of course you can repeat calling `mw.show` and `app.exec_` in that order.  If the window is hidden before calling app.exec_ you probably cannot gain control back from the Qt event loop, thus requiring forcible quitting which is probably what you might refer to as potentially dangerous - but given that we are just playing around it should not be a problem.  We can try to do something else too

```
>>> def hello():
...     print 'Hello world'
...
>>> helloaction = QtGui.QAction('&Hello', mw)
>>> helloaction.triggered.connect(hello)
True
>>> filemenu.addAction(helloaction)
>>> mw.show()
>>> app.exec_()
```

You will note a new action below the `Exit` action, and selecting that will print 'Hello World' into your terminal.

* Of course, you can spawn an interactive python shell after starting the app using the [`code.interact`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html#code.interact) function in a separate thread, but that's a whole other thing you have to read on.

Comment: It was typo. I wanted to say "troublesome" or "need different manner" or "Is there  some trap?". Because many tutorial site don't use Python interactive shell. So I thought there are some reason.

Comment: Ah, that!  Yes, `QApplication.exec_()` will take control away from the interactive shell since it needs to run in the main thread, and if you try to run it in a separate thread it will complain and terminate.